# meta viewprot not working in iframe on iOS device

Tags: ios, css, responsive

Recently I have made a site responsive for mobile device adding following tag

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

The site load within a `iframe`. In Android the site fit perfectly within iframe but in `iOS` it is not fitting. User can move around left and right. I don't have control over the iframe. My site will be load within third party site. So I have to do something with the site. So what will be the possible solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? currently having the same problem.

Comment: @LewisBrowne Hey, I might redesign some of the HTML element that caused the problem. It's been almost nine months, can't remember the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set css for `iframe`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {    
    iframe {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```